# Jekyll exclude folder not matches

Tags: jekyll

I can't exclude `js/` folder for watching without excluding `dist/js/` in `_config.yml`. My folder structure is the following:

```
- js/
- dist/js/
```

For some reason if I add `js/` to the exclude array, Jekyll excludes both. I need to exclude `js/` because it builds twice.

Seems like it searches for all the matches, not just `js/`. It doesn't even work with `/js` or `/js/`.

This is my `_config.yml` exclude array:

```
exclude: [js/, node_modules/, Gruntfile.js, package.json]
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add a trailing slash for folders.
This works fine in Jekyll 3.2.1:

```
exclude:
  - js
  - node_modules
  - Gruntfile.js
  - package.json


include:
  - dist
```

Comment: No, it does not work. I still have the same issue. It keeps ignoring `dist/js`

Comment: Hard to know what differ in your case without a link to a repository. 
You can always add:


`include:
  - dist/js`

Comment: I don't have a repository yet. It still fails with include, written before or after the exclude statement.